# Inserting into array on SELECT at index in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, insert

I'm using a [Postgres CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) to recurse through a parent-child tree. The following script will recurse from root to leaf and append to the end of `path` (**`ARRAY`**).

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  // get roots
  SELECT entity_id, parent_id, ARRAY[entity_id] as path
     FROM entity
     WHERE parent_id is null

  UNION ALL

  // recursive step
  SELECT c.entity_id, c.parent_id, path || c.entity_id
     FROM tree t
     JOIN entity c ON c.parent_id = t.entity_id
)

SELECT path 
  FROM tree t 
  WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM tree WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL);
```

Instead of appending to the end of the `path` at each step, I would like to insert into the array by a `index` column. **Is it possible to do this within SELECT?**

#### Hypothetical Solution

```
SELECT  path[c.index] = c.entity_id
   FROM tree t
   JOIN entity c ON c.parent_id = t.entity_id
```

#### Expected output

```
| entity_id  | index       | parent_id |
|:-----------|------------:|:----------|
| a          |          3  | d         |
| b          |          5  | a         |
| c          |          1  | (none)    |
| d          |          2  | c         |
```

**`path = [c,d,a,(none),b]`**

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I don't understand where the `index` comes from? The expression ` path[c.index] = path[entity_id]` is certainly valid if `c.index` and `entity_id` are both integer values

Comment: Corrected to `path[c.index] = c.entity_id`. That expression returns a boolean which throws error on union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function implements the assignment `arr[idx]:= elem` and returns `arr`. If necessary the array is automatically expanded to accommodate the new element.

```
create or replace function array_set_element(arr text[], elem text, idx int)
returns text[] language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if cardinality(arr) < idx then
        arr:= arr || array_fill(null::text, array[idx- cardinality(arr)]);
    end if;
    arr[idx]:= elem;
    return arr;
end $$;
```

Example:

```
select array_set_element('{a, b}'::text[], 'e', 5);

 array_set_element 
------------------------
 {a,b,NULL,NULL,e}
(1 row)
```

Use the function in your query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT entity_id, parent_id, array_set_element('{}'::text[], entity_id, index) as path
     FROM entity
     WHERE parent_id is null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.entity_id, c.parent_id, array_set_element(path, c.entity_id, c.index)
     FROM tree t
     JOIN entity c ON c.parent_id = t.entity_id
)

SELECT path 
FROM tree t 
WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM tree WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL);

      path      
----------------
 {c,d,a,NULL,b}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked as intended! Replaced `cardinality(arr)` with `array_length(arr,1)` for version < 9.4